# Pygame image loading error when accessing Python through another Python file

Tags: python, path, pygame

There's one file which is run with Python33, it has this line of code:

`os.startfile(r'rungame\xsim.py')`

That opens up a file in Python32, called xsim.py, and that works fine. However, xsim, which uses pygame modules, does not run as it would usually run. It cannot load its images when accessed this way, the first image is 'winp.png', and it is in the same folder as xsim.py (rungame). Here is the code which loads it:

`pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load('winp.png'))`

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been fixed. The current working directory was the location of the first file, not the file in need of the pictures which was inside the folder 'rungame', so that is where it looked for winp.png when no path was specified.